# Google Chrome Ul horizontal menu ghost item

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I needed to create a top menu in wordpress so I could fill an yet-to-be-determined number of items. I found an elegant solution here in Stack Overflow using CSS `display:table`, it works nice everywhere, except in chrome...

The site in question is: http://joao.beno.net.br

If I `check element` the ul, disable the css rule, and then re-enable it, everything fits right...

Edit:
Bad: http://tinypic.com/r/24qlah1/5

Comment: Looks correct to me on Chrome,

Why not just float the lis left instead of as a table

Comment: Ha... Magically solved... Or not, some times i hit ´F5´ and it is ok, other times it get wrong again... @Chad, i used table because i want the menu items to adjust itself to the width of the wrapper no matter how many items i put in it, and to solve a problem with vertical align of the text inside the ´a´'s...